# How to fix the AddScriptCss extension?

Tags: server, mediawiki

I get the following message on my webpage: `AddScriptCss: invalid URI`

Furthermore, I get the messages with respect to the following character set:

```
{{#addscript: src=/waypoints|type=js|pos=head}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently, the source pointed to a directory that wasn't set up correctly in my LocalSettings.php. Simply fixing the directory name resolved this issue.